# Can I install libexpect on my Mac and use it in C with Xcode?

Tags: c, macos, xcode5

I'd like to use the `libexpect` api http://linux.die.net/man/3/libexpect, but I'm unsure how to obtain this code and use it in Xcode. I'm learning `C` and would like to build some cli tools.

Answer (score 0):

It's already installed, in Terminal:

```
man expect
```

https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/expect.1.html

Comment: Yes `expect` is installed on OSX, but how would I use it in C?

Comment: You asked if you could install libexpect and use it with C; The answer is yes to both. Have you read the man page to gain an understanding through the provided examples? That's probably going to give you a better idea on how you would use it.

Comment: Yes, I read the man page. It says to use `libexpect(3)`, that's the man page I posted in my original post. In that example it shows an include statement `include "expect_tcl.h"`. This is where I'm stuck, how do I install (or use) this library? If I try to include expect, or tcl/expect it can not find it.